# running jogl VBO on netbeans 7.4

Tags: jogl, vbo

I am new in jogl and try to render rectangle by using VBO.
There are given two array: first arrey is

```
float vertex[] = {-2.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f,
            2.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f,
            -2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f,
            2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f
        };
```

second array is

```
float colors[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
        };
```

and then I try to initialize vertex buffers

```
        pointsbf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertex.length);
        colorsbf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(colors.length);
        pointsbf.put(vertex);
        colorsbf.put(colors); 
        pointsbf.rewind();
        colorsbf.rewind();
```

the code above has been written in INIT() function;
The code bellow has been written in DISPLAY() function;

```
     gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, pointsbf);
    gl.glColorPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorsbf);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalNumVerts);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

but the code after running shows just black screen(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you modified the projection matrix and the model view matrix? If your vertices aren't in the view frustum, you won't see them.

You can use my example and modify it to use VBOs:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL#Code_example

Keep in mind that [the official JogAmp forum](http://forum.jogamp.org) is a better place to get answers about JOGL.